# "Name has already been taken" in RSpec/FactoryGirl with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to run a very basic spec test and it fails with the error "*Name has already been taken*".

**Update** belongs to **User** who has many **Roles**.

**user** model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_engineer, class: User do
    id 1
    email 'someone@somewhere.com'
    roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:engineer)]}
  end
end
```

**roles** model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string
#  description :text
#

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :engineer, class: Role do
    id 3
    name 'Engineer'
    description 'He is the chosen one'
  end
end
```

**updates** model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: updates
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  content       :text
#  user_id       :integer
#  ticket_id :integer
#

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :update do
    content "This is a test update"
    association :user, factory: :user_engineer
  end
end
```

**update_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Update, type: :model do
  let(:update){ FactoryGirl.create :update }
  it { expect(update).to be_valid }
end
```

This is the error:

```
Update
  example at ./spec/models/update_spec.rb:19 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Update 
     Failure/Error: roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:engineer)]}

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

How can I pass the tests?!

**EDIT:** By adding the sequence line I was suggested, I get the following error after running `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop`:

```
1) Update 
     Failure/Error: roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:engineer)]}

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "roles_pkey"
       DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
       : INSERT INTO "roles" ("id", "name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: can you run only this `it { expect(update).to be_valid }` spec, and see the error is coming or not. I think the error comes from other code side effects..

Comment: what other should I post that could help debug ?

Comment: Ok, tell me the line number of `it { expect(update).to be_valid }` and the file name.

Comment: Updated the original post with the exact error If that's what you mean.

Comment: it seems your test data is not getting cleared. If you run the spec like that, it shouldn't say `name` exist. Because you are creating just only one *role*.

Comment: I tried doing db:drop for RAILS_ENV=test and setup it again but didn't help.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Why did you remove your reply ? I was going to accept it.

Comment: I don't get either what you meant ?

Comment: I don't remember what you did because you deleted it but now i see it.

Comment: I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from your error it is clear that you have a *uniq* validation on `name` attribute, you should be then use [`sequence`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) technique.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :engineer, class: Role do
    id 3
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Engineer-#{n}" }
    description 'He is the chosen one'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for the user model

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_engineer, class: User do
    id 1
    email 'someone@somewhere.com'
    roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:engineer, name: "new_engineer")]}
  end
end
```

Since there is a uniq constraint on the name attribute, I think there is already a engineer record in your test database which got added first time you run test case, So it is better clear the test DB before or after running the test cases.

Put the following block of code in the spec/rails_helper.rb file.

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Comment: This is really not helpful to understand why the error comes. Do you see any evidence of it ?

Comment: cool, and still your first code wrong. Rather ask OP to use _sequence_ .